# windows forms: Set a background image

Tags: c#, winforms, background

I am trying to set a background image on a windows form. How would I go about doing this correctly, when it comes to different resolutions and screen scaling.

I am aware that I can set a background image using this piece of code:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.BackgroundImage
```

I want the background image to fill the entire form. I think I find the correct dimensions using

```
this.ClientRectangle.Width
this.ClientRectangle.Height
```

in the windows form class.

I can stretch the image to fill the entire background with these numbers, or I can calculate the difference in ratio, and stretch the image accordingly, but keep the aspect ratio.

What I don't understand is what happens when you scale your windows desktop, from 100% to 125%, 150% or another scaling settings, the numbers reported by:

```
this.ClientRectangle.Width
this.ClientRectangle.Height
```

Don't seem to report a number that is similar to the increase in percentage.
At a desktop scale of 100% the width is: 704, but with a desktop scale of 125%, the width is now: 802. With an increase of 25% from 100%, the new number should have been 880.

It doesn't seem like I will always be able to fill the entire background, unless I stretch the image, or use different images.

Comment: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this.BackgroundImageLayout`.

For instance: `this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;`